# Why does Actors truck has oil in the radiator?

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz, truck

Actros V6 engine. There is engine oil in the radiator, but no water in engine oil. I have replaced the oil cooler, but the oil is there again.

Then I changed the head gaskets and check the head, but the problem continues. Oil coming very slowly, maybe one or two months need.give me help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the cooling system flushed during either of these maintenance events? I'm not talking about drained ... I mean flushed. Chemical flush may be needed to completely clean the oil out of the water.

Comment: Is it really engine oil and not transmission fluid?

Comment: Its Engine oil Sure